# What if Stockfish had infinite computing power?

Tags: stockfish

If Stockfish had infinite computing power, or perhaps connected to all Google servers, etc. would it be able to solve the perfect chess moves after 10 moves? Or be able to create the perfect game directly? What would happen?

Comment: This sort of counterfactual is a call for speculation rather than a question which has a right or wrong answer.

Comment: It would run out of memory eventually.

Comment: How infinite is infinite?  A billion computers each pumping out a billion brute-force moves per second?  If you're lucky, and you're young, and you started the computations now, maybe you'd live to see the day when the 10th move (20 ply deep) is entirely calculated.

Answer (score 2):

No.

- What do you mean by "perfect" chess moves after 10 moves? We don't know they are perfect until the game ends in checkmate! You'll need go mucher deeper than 10 moves. You can't even solve King's Gambit in just 10 moves.
- The Stockfish algorithm **heavily** skips stupid moves off the search tree. It will **not search** everything no matter what CPU power you give it. You're actually talking about a brute-force engine (search all the possible moves). No, Stockfish is much **smarter** than that.
- Nothing really happen. You could publish a new paper, but your results would not change the world. We don't need to know what happens after 10 moves, we want to know what happens after 100 moves.

Comment: I meant after the first 10 moves, would it be able to analyze the entire outcome(s) of the game and thus make it impossible to win against it?

Comment: @Habbo: It is completely unclear to me what the role of  the "10 moves" is in your question. Also, as mentioned stockfish does not analayze all possible lines, but only those it considers interesting/good. The current computer power is very far from solving chess. Currently the best that is known is perfect play for endgames with at most 7 pieces (black and white pieces combined including kings). Doing the same for 8 pieces is significantly harder as storage requirements increase exponentially with every piece.